# Importing CSV into Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a CSV dataset that looks like this:

```
FirstAge,SecondAge,FirstCountry,SecondCountry,Income,NAME
41,41,USA,UK,113764,John
53,43,USA,USA,145963,Fred
47,37,USA,UK,42857,Dan
47,44,UK,USA,95352,Mark
```

I'm trying to load it into Python 3.6 with this code:

```
>>> from numpy import genfromtxt

>>> my_data = genfromtxt('first.csv', delimiter=',')
>>> print(train_data)
```

Output:

```
 [[             nan              nan              nan              nan
               nan              nan]
 [  4.10000000e+01   4.10000000e+01              nan              nan
    1.13764000e+05              nan]
 [  5.30000000e+01   4.30000000e+01              nan              nan
    1.45963000e+05              nan]
 ..., 
 [  2.10000000e+01   3.00000000e+01              nan              nan
    1.19929000e+05              nan]
 [  6.90000000e+01   6.40000000e+01              nan              nan
    1.52667000e+05              nan]
 [  2.00000000e+01   1.90000000e+01              nan              nan
    1.05077000e+05              nan]]
```

I've looked at the Numpy docs and I don't see anything about this.

Comment: Is `USA` or `UK` a number ?! What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: The issue that you may be running into is the numpy wants to parse your data as a numeric type and this could be causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: The numeric columns/rows are right, just in float.  The `nan` stand in for strings that can't be interpreted as floats.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the an issue that you could be running into is the data that you are trying to parse is not all numerics and this could potentially cause unexpected behavior.

One way to detect the types would be to try and identify the types before they are added to your array.  For example:

```
for obj in my_data:
    if type(obj) == int:
        # process or add your data to numpy
    else:
        # cast or discard the data
```

Comment: Without wanting to attack someone (in some unfair way): this answer has a very very low quality, mostly *indicates* the source of the problem, does not give a cure and presents pseudo-code which is far far away from running (this is the most upsetting for me). I don't understand how to accept this one, especially 30 minutes after asking.

Comment: Sascha, you are correct in that I am pointing out the problem and not providing a defined solution.  If it would be in the best interest of this post, I can remove my answer.

Comment: Well... not my decision. But the first statement is wrong (although that's numpy's specialty) as numpy can also store strings, even just for some columns in these record-arrays. And the pseudo-code is very bad and it's not really too hard to express your idea into code (probably using *isinstance*).

Comment: OK, valid points. I just tried to remove my answer and because it is the accepted one it cannot be removed.

Comment: Interesting. I also did not know that. So don't bother. We will see, if OP recognizes the other answers (2 good quality ones).

Answer (score 2):

Go with `pandas`, it will save you the trouble:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative from using `pandas` is to use `csv` library

```
import csv
import numpy as np
ls = list(csv.reader(open('first.csv', 'r')))
val_array = np.array(ls)[1::] # exclude first row (columns name)
```

Comment: I get an array of string dtype with your way.

Comment: Ah, yeah. You have to cast each to other types later if using `csv.reader`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `dtype` argument:

```
import numpy as np

output = np.genfromtxt("main.csv", delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype='f, f, |S6, |S6, f, |S6')

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[( 41.,  41., b'USA', b'UK',  113764., b'John')
 ( 53.,  43., b'USA', b'USA',  145963., b'Fred')
 ( 47.,  37., b'USA', b'UK',   42857., b'Dan')
 ( 47.,  44., b'UK', b'USA',   95352., b'Mark')]
```

Comment: I'm to lazy to check, but i thought about ```skip_header``` as the first row looked that bad. In this case, using it, automatic inference should work too (no need to manually define it). But finally a good answer (which really answers the question).

Comment: I think numpy would infer it but it does not, it puts it like nan.

Comment: If you want to infer the types you could use `pandas` as shown in another answer.

Comment: Sure. I always use pandas for that kind of stuff. But i'm puzzled by numpy's behaviour (as this inference is really easy and np should do that too). But nevermind. This is a good answer, maybe a bit too compact, but compared to the others it shines.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: See my answer on how to let `genfromtxt` deduce both field names and dtypes.

Comment: @hpaulj  Does not recognize types, does not recognize numbers. You have the same answer when you run: `np.genfromtxt("main.csv", delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype='str')`

Comment: My `Out[101]` is similar to your `output` - but with integer fields.

Answer (score 1):

With a few general paramters `genfromtxt` can  read this file (in PY3 here):

```
In [100]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack43444219.txt', delimiter=',', names=True, dtype=None)
In [101]: data
Out[101]: 
array([(41, 41, b'USA', b'UK', 113764, b'John'),
       (53, 43, b'USA', b'USA', 145963, b'Fred'),
       (47, 37, b'USA', b'UK',  42857, b'Dan'),
       (47, 44, b'UK', b'USA',  95352, b'Mark')], 
      dtype=[('FirstAge', '<i4'), ('SecondAge', '<i4'), ('FirstCountry', 'S3'), ('SecondCountry', 'S3'), ('Income', '<i4'), ('NAME', 'S4')])
```

This is a structured array.  2 fields are integer, 2 are string (byte string by default), another integer, and string.

The default `genfromtxt` reads all lines as data.  I uses `names=True` to get to use the first line a field names.

It also tries to read all strings a float (default dtype).  The string columns then load as `nan`.

All of this is in the `genfromtxt` docs.  Admittedly they are long, but they aren't hard to find.

Access fields by name, `data['FirstName']` etc.

---

Using the`csv` reader gives a 2d array of strings:

```
In [102]: ls =list(csv.reader(open('stack43444219.txt','r')))
In [103]: ls
Out[103]: 
[['FirstAge', 'SecondAge', 'FirstCountry', 'SecondCountry', 'Income', 'NAME'],
 ['41', '41', 'USA', 'UK', '113764', 'John'],
 ['53', '43', 'USA', 'USA', '145963', 'Fred'],
 ['47', '37', 'USA', 'UK', '42857', 'Dan'],
 ['47', '44', 'UK', 'USA', '95352', 'Mark']]
In [104]: arr=np.array(ls)
In [105]: arr
Out[105]: 
array([['FirstAge', 'SecondAge', 'FirstCountry', 'SecondCountry', 'Income',
        'NAME'],
       ['41', '41', 'USA', 'UK', '113764', 'John'],
       ['53', '43', 'USA', 'USA', '145963', 'Fred'],
       ['47', '37', 'USA', 'UK', '42857', 'Dan'],
       ['47', '44', 'UK', 'USA', '95352', 'Mark']], 
      dtype='<U13')
```