# Importing HTML code into CSV using python

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

I have an HTML with data that I want to bring into python and put into a CSV. I'm not sure which package and program will allow me to complete this as I've tried a few different ones with no success (bs4 and urllib).

This is the HTML link:

https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Volume/Details/F/8478/20200807/F?tradeDate=20200807

Out of interest, what kind of HTML link is this? It appears to almost be in CSV format already. Apologies if this is a silly question. I've tried to search file types on the internet too.

I tried a URL request on this web link but received an error when trying to make the request:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

cme_url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Volume/Details/F/8478/20200807/F?tradeDate=20200807"

#opening up connection
uClient = uReq(cme_url)
```

I have scoured StackOver for examples which could solve my questions, but I was unsuccessful. For example, this example didn't help because it's using a specifically CSV file already: [Importing CSV into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444219/importing-csv-into-python)

I really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The data format in the URL you provided is almost in [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Your question is "How to convert JSON file to CSV" in fact.

Python itself can solve this problem, with [JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can read json from a URL and convert it to csv in a couple steps:

- Use **requests** to get the json text and convert it to a dictionary
- Use **pandas** to convert the dictionary to a csv file

I assume you only want the month data.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Volume/Details/F/8478/20200807/F?tradeDate=20200807'
r = requests.get(url)
dj = r.json()
        
df = pd.DataFrame(dj['monthData'])
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Output (out.csv)

```
month,monthID,globex,openOutcry,totalVolume,blockVolume,efpVol,efrVol,eooVol,efsVol,subVol,pntVol,tasVol,deliveries,opnt,aon,atClose,change,strike,exercises
AUG 20,AUG-20-Calls,"10,007",0,"10,007",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,"9,372","-1,103",0,0
SEP 20,SEP-20-Calls,"1,316",0,"1,316",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,"2,899",47,0,0
OCT 20,OCT-20-Calls,115,0,115,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,614,32,0,0
NOV 20,NOV-20-Calls,16,0,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,68,6,0,0
DEC 20,DEC-20-Calls,13,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,105,-3,0,0
JAN 21,JAN-21-Calls,6,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,5,4,0,0
DEC 21,DEC-21-Calls,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-,-,1,0,0,0
```